# How to remove device from safe list?

Tags: gmail

This morning I logged to gmail from a strange computer. Google recognizes this and goes through three-factor autentication to check it's really myself.

Now I can go to my account from my habitual computer and tell google it was really really myself, or I can tell it it was not myself.

I want to tell google that it was me, but that it should check again the next time someone tries to connect from that computer (3FA and everything).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, check out Google security settings and revoke devices associated with the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove access to your account for that device
[image: removingDeviceAccessPicture]
[image: disableDevicePicture]
Now log back in to your Google account. When it asks to not ask for 3FA again for a month, select no. 
And now you can go back to your security settings and tell Google that the device is you.

Answer (score -2):

When Google prompts "Is this really you?", simply **do not respond** yes or no. If you're on your phone just swipe away the notification instead of responding to it. Google should prompt you next time this happens, assuming you have logged out properly.